# Bootstrap two-column layout with equal heights

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the latest Bootstrap and have a simple two column layout. I want to fill the div contained in the right column with color. To do that properly, I need to have the same height as the container, but `height: 100%` doesn't work.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            a<br/>
            b<br/>
            c
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div style="background-color: red;">
                Just text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This example uses the `row-eq-height` as defined by the Bootstrap framework.

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

This is how it looks

[image]

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/84a0crjd/

Comment: Do you require a bootstrap only version or can we use all the CSS we want?

Comment: It's all good. And I'm only concerned with modern browsers, so you can skip all the IE nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is `background-color`, then you can use a [pseudo element](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-solving-the-equal-height-column-conundrum--cms-20403).  You'll have to know the parent container's padding though, which is unfortunate.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jralvarez28/84a0crjd/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            a<br/>
            b<br/>
            c
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div style="background-color: red;">
                Just text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.col-xs-6:last-of-type {
    position: relative;
}
.col-xs-6:last-of-type > div::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 30px); /* 100% of .col-xs-6 minus left and right padding */
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think this is way too much of a hack for me to use... :/

Comment: Yes, it is hackish.  I'm interested in seeing other answers though, because I'm sure I'll need to do something like this one day as well. :P

Comment: I've found a solution! `flex` was the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with `flex` boxes I've come up with a solution to this problem.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-xs-6 left">
            <div class="left-background">
                a<br/>
                b<br/>
                c
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 right">
            <div class="right-background">
                Just text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `CSS` implementation is below. The basic structure is: `row > column > background container`. The key bit is `flex: 1` in the background container, this instructs the siblings to have equal size.

```
.row-eq-height {
    display: flex;
}
.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.right-background {
    background-color: red;
    flex: 1;
}
.left-background {
    background-color: green;
    flex: 1;
}
```

The demo is on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84a0crjd/).

Comment: Well done for finding your own solution. If you want to support all modern  browsers please refer to this [link](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). You'll notice that you do require some prefixes even with recent browsers.

Comment: @jaunt thanks for that. I had the idea that flex was well enough supported on most recent browser versions.